# Why isn't my daemon thread increasing the auto icecream per second (aips) in my game code?

Tags: python

So I am coding a game where you make and sell ice cream.  I am trying to make a aips(auto icecream per second) function to run in a different thread.  I tried to make a daemon thread to increase icecream, but it didn't do anything.  Here is my code:

```
from random import randint, choice
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

icecream = 0
dollars = 0
machineLvl = 1
ips = 1
playing = True

def aips():
    while True:
        global ips
        global icecream 
        icecream += ips
        time.sleep(1)



def make_icecream (lvl, icecream):
    icecream += lvl
    print(f' + {str(lvl)} ')
    return icecream


def sell_icecream (icecream, coins):
        coins += icecream
        icecream = 0
        return [icecream, coins]


def stats(coins, icecream, lvl):
    print(f'''    dollars: {coins}
    ice cream: {icecream}
    Level: {lvl}''')


while playing:
    command = input(">  ")
    if command == 'sell':
        icecream, dollars = sell_icecream (icecream, dollars)
    elif command == 'make':
        icecream = make_icecream (machineLvl, icecream)
    elif command == 'stats':
        stats(dollars, icecream, machineLvl)
    elif command == 'stop':
        playing == False
    else: 
        print("Error, could not read command.")

print("Bye!")
    

t1 = Thread(target = aips(), daemon = True, )
t1.start()
```

I tried running the program, but it didn't work.  I tried 2 threads, but it still didn't work.  I was expecting icecream to increase by 1 each time, but it never increased.  How do I make it increase properly?

Comment: Please show the code you used with two threads. (The current code 'runs the game', and only starts the daemon thread after the game is over.)

Comment: `playing == False` has no effect